# Module written in 2.1.3 does not work in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: phtml, magento2.3.1

I just upgraded my site from Magento 2.1 to 2.3 and while most of my site still works, I have a particular code which has partially failed to work. The code is supposed to get the "details" attribute and display it on my product page, but somehow I am unable to get the data anymore. The alt image still works, so I have no idea what's up. Help is much appreciated!

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product additional attributes template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
 */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct()
?>
<table class="moreinfo">
<tr>
<td id="altimage">
<?php
$images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
//$images = $this->getGalleryImages($_product);

//print "\n" . ' here2 ' . get_class($images) . ' :: <br/>' . "\n"; 
if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $item = $image->getData();
        if ( !isset($item['media_type']) || $item['media_type'] != 'image' || 'alt' != $item['label'] || !isset($item['url'])) { continue; }

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        // 'product_page_image_medium_no_frame'
        $postImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_medium_no_frame')->setImageFile($image->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(700)->getUrl();
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $postImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item['label']; ?>" aria-hidden="false" style="max-height: 500px">
        <?php

        break;
    }
}

?>
</td>
<td id="productdescriptiondt" class="hidden-xs" style="min-width:20em; vertical-align: middle">
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="col data" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="productdescriptionmobile" class="visible-xs">
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('More Information') ?></caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="col data" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
</div> 
<?php 

// $_product->getAttributeSetId(); // 9 for Clocks

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
$attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($_product->getAttributeSetId());
$attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();

if ( 'Clocks' == $attribute_set_name ) {

  echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('product_view_clocks')->toHtml();
}
elseif ( 'Watches' == $attribute_set_name ) {

  echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('product_view_watches')->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: Can you please  confirm block class is  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" in catalog_product_view,xml.